# Select fields based on permission field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

Hello guys i am having a problem getting from database only fields that are permitted by the user.
So my schema is:

```
var profileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    authId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Auth'},
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
    am: Number,
    email: String,
    location: String,
    languages: [String],
    birth_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    reg_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    last_log: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    permissions: {
        location: {type: Boolean,Default:true},
        birth_date: {type: Boolean,Default:true},
        email: {type: Boolean,Default:true},
        am: {type: Boolean,Default:true},
        subjects: {type: Boolean,Default:true},
        files: {type: Boolean,Default:true},
        posts: {type: Boolean,Default:true}
    },
    ip: String,
    subjects: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subject'}],
    files: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'FileIndex'}],
    posts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}],
    notifications: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Notifications'}]
});
```

And I am trying to get only fields that in permission field have true which means it's permitted. So I am running the following query :

```
database.Profile.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).exec(function (err, profile) { 
    console.log(profile);
    res.send(profile);
});
```

How do I select only the fields that are permitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, It ,might get you what you want:

```
database.Profile.findOne({_id: req.params.id},{location:$.permissions.location , birth_date:$.permissions.birth_date, email:$.permissions.email, am:$.permissions.am, subjects:$.permissions.subjects, files:$.permissions.files, posts:$.permissions.posts}).exec(function (err, profile) { 
    console.log(profile);
    res.send(profile);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a query with the **[`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)** method chained since documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, not [MongooseDocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js) and manipulate the object returned by removing the keys as determined by the permissions object fields:

```
Object.filter = function( obj, predicate) {
    var result = {}, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !predicate(obj[key])) {
            result[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
};

database.Profile.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).lean().exec(function (err, doc) { 
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(doc);
    console.log(doc.permissions);
    var filtered = Object.filter(doc.permissions, 
        function (key){ return doc.permissions[key]; }
    );
    console.log(filtered);
    res.send(filtered);
});
```

---

Another alternative that uses the Mongoose's projection **[`select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)** method would be to make two queries; the first one will return the whole document and the next will query the same document but project the fields based on the permissions object fields:

The following shows this:

```
database.Profile.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).lean().exec(function (err, doc) { 
    console.log(doc);
    console.log(doc.permissions);
    var projection = Object.keys(doc.permissions)
                           .filter(function (key){ return doc.permissions[key]; })
                           .join(' ');
    console.log(projection);
    database.Profile.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
        .select(projection)
        .exec(function (err, profile) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            res.send(profile);
        });    
});
```

Comment: I solve it with the second solution you suggested right after i posted the question but this one needs two queries.I didn`t checked the first one because the first answer from 'ravi shankar' works just fine!Thank you.

Comment: @AlexisPavlidis No worries, not one of the best solutions but just an alternative if you don't know the permissions keys beforehand. Overall I think Ravi's answer suffices hence the +1.